# Display Date VC2012 windows forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to display the current time on an app i'm developing.
I have a label and a timer control and the following code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label16.Text = TimeOfDay
End Sub
```

Shouldn't this work? I've been searching and it should work, is there a way for it to display the date as well?

Thanks for the help,
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as this

```
Label16.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

Other variations

```
Label16.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() ' just the today date in short format'

Label16.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() ' just the current time in short format'
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the suggestions, i have tried those 3 variations and none works, when i press start debugging it just keeps saying label16 :S

Comment: Did you start the timer? If you set a breakpoint on the line that should update the label it will be hit?

Comment: Thanks, i had forgotten to start the timer :S